# Appended data-attribute listener on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four appended divs with the first featuring an active class.

```
<div class="col active" data-column="1"></div>
<div class="col" data-column="2"></div>
<div class="col" data-column="3"></div>
<div class="col" data-column="4"></div>
```

I have an on click function set up so that whatever column you click on(assuming it's not the currently active div) loses the active class and adds it to whichever div you click.

With that said, I'm trying set up a listener(keep in mind all these divs are appended based on a previous/unrelated click event) so that whatever data-column has the class "active" use a switch statement to log some text to the console.

```
var columnListener = $('.col').attr('data-column');
$(document).on('change', columnListener, function() {
  if ( $(columnListener).hasClass("active") ) {
    switch(columnListener) {
        case 1:
            console.log("first column");
        break;
        case 2: 
            console.log("second column");
        break;
        case 3:
            console.log("third column");
        break;
        case 4: 
            console.log("fourth column");
        break;
        default:

        break;
    }
  }
});
```

At the moment, nothing seems to be logging so I'm assuming it's the way I'm setting up my function. If anyone has any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly, I'd greatly appreciated the input.

Thank you

Comment: why on("change") ? Shouldnt you be doing this on"click" ?

Comment: @karthick Not married to on("change"), essentially taking a shot in the dark. But trying to get away from a specific on("click") event because when they're initially appended, one of the divs will have the active class.

Comment: `$('.col').attr('data-column')` won't do what you think it will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use jQuery for this, here's an example of what I've done.

```js
var columns = document.querySelectorAll('.col[data-column]');

for (var i = 0, s = columns.length; i < s; i++) {
  var col = columns[i];
  col.addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var j = 0, z = columns.length; j < z; j++) {
      var temp = columns[j];
      temp.className = "col";
    }
    console.clear();
    this.className += " active";
    x = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-column"))
    console.log(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"][x - 1] + " column")
  });
}
```

```css
div.col {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
}

div.col.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="col active" data-column="1"></div>
<div class="col" data-column="2"></div>
<div class="col" data-column="3"></div>
<div class="col" data-column="4"></div>
```

Comment: No problem! Just be sure to also thank @chrisz he implemented the nicer way of logging which column you clicked on, I just copied your switch statement. Either way, it's no problem at all, happy to help!